# In new activity application terminate at try to setText() to a textview

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I follow the link 
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

to send a string from one activity to another.There is a text view in second activity and I try to display the string from 1st activity.But application terminate at that line,

mainactivity

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,DisplayActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE,Data);

    startActivity(intent);
```

display activity

```
TextView listname;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    listname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

     Intent intent = getIntent();
    String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    listname.setText(message);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
```

application terminate at line `listname.setText(message);`

Comment: always show the stacktrace...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change order. `setContentView()` have to be called before you start initialising widgets.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
listname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);
```

Exactly what docs says:

> setContentView method set the activity content from a layout resource.
>   The resource will be inflated, adding all top-level views to the
>   activity.

In other words, setContentView() method is layout inflation and it creates all instances of UI elements which are contained in layout and then attach layout to Activity. So at first must be called setContentView and then initialisation of UI elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try Same Code in DisplayActivity This way..

```
TextView listname;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_display);
listname=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.msg);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
listname.setText(message);
```